# limitar publicaçoes Parse

Tags: java, android

Pessoal seguinte to fazendo um app onde a pessoa publica fotos

gostaria de limitar a publicaçao a 10 publicaçoes por pessoa e quando a pessoa tentar postar mais imagens dar uma mensagem de erro

alguem sabe como eu poderia fazer isso

aqui esta a açao de publicar e salvar no parse

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    //testar o processo de retorno dos dados
    if (requestCode == 1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {


        //Recuperar local do recurso
        Uri localImagemSelecionada = data.getData();



        //Recupera a imagem do local que foi selecionada
        try {
            Bitmap imagem = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), localImagemSelecionada);

            /*
            Comprimir imagem no formato PNG
             */
            ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            imagem.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 75, stream);



            /*Cria  Arrays de Bytes da imagem formato PNG 
            */
            byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();


            /*Cria arquivos com formato proprio do Parse para PNG              */
            SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("ddmmaaaahhmmss");
            String nomeImagem = dateFormat.format(new Date());
            ParseFile arquivoParse = new ParseFile(nomeImagem + "imagem.png", byteArray);

            /*Monta um objeto para salvar no Parse
             */
            final ParseObject parseObject = new ParseObject("Imagem");
            parseObject.put("username", ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getUsername());

            /*Atribui 2 entradas de dados no objeto "imagem", para PNG */

            parseObject.put("imagem", arquivoParse);




            //Salvar os dados
            parseObject.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
                @Override
                public void done(ParseException e) {

                    if (e == null) {//Sucesso



                        String idObjeto = parseObject.getObjectId();

                        Intent intent = new Intent(PublicarImagemActivity.this, descricaoActivity.class);
                        intent.putExtra("idObjeto", idObjeto);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        finish();
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Sua imagem foi publicada!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                    } else {//Erro
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Erro ao postar sua imagem, tente novamente!",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }


                }
```

Comment: Tem algumas formas que é possível fazer, tanto do lado onde recebe a imagem, quanto do lado do Android. Se quiser você pode deixar especificado na sua pergunta, senão ela vai acabar sendo um pouco ampla.

Comment: voce poderia me dizer qual formas seriam?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Da para fazer dos dois lados, tanto no Android quanto no seu *Server*.Caso você tenha uma coleção relativamente pequena de chaves para salvar, que é uma opção para essa situação, use as APIs [SharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html).

`SharedPreferences` são utilizadas em situações onde não há necessidade de criação de um banco de dados, ou até mesmo quando há pouco número de dados a ser armazenado. Em linhas gerais, este armazenamento pode consistir em diversos tipos de dados, inclusive inteiros.

As `SharedPreferences` consiste em uma interface que permite acessar e modificar dados de preferência de usuário. O valor armazenado apresenta-se sob formato chave-valor ou *key-value*, ou seja, cada preferência armazenada possui uma identificação ou chave e associada a ela está um valor. Ela permite armazenamento de diversos tipos de valor, como `int`, `float`, `Strings`, `booleans` e `sets` de *Strings*. Veja um exemplo de como é usado:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
editor.putInt("qndFotosEnviadas", 0);
editor.commit();
```

Quando você adicionar uma foto, você muda o valor da chave `qndFotosEnviadas` incrementando `+1`.

Para resgatar o valor antes de incrementar, você pode fazer desta forma:

```
int qndFotos = sharedPref.getInt("qndFotosEnviadas", 0);
if(qndFotos<=10){

    qndFotos++;
    editor.putInt("qndFotosEnviadas", qndFotos);
    editor.commit();
    // chama função para tirar foto

} else {
    // exibe mensagem você não pode enviar mais que 10
}
```

<sup>**Nota**: Jamais, em hipótese alguma, salve senhas de usuários nas *SharedPreferences*, inclusive recomenda-se que nenhum dado pessoal de usuário, como cartão de crédito, telefone, e senhas sejam armazenadas de alguma forma no aparelho.</sup>

Comment: o comando getActivity fica vermelho, você poderia me dar um exemplo aonde eu colocaria a linha de código? obrigado

Comment: No lugar de getActivity, coloque this.

Comment: sem sucesso, o codigo nao aparece nem um erro mas continua publicando normal

Comment: Mano, sua pergunta não tem todo o código necessário para fazer uma resposta mais completa. Só estou mostrando como é possível fazer usando SharedPreferences, apesar de existir outras formas. Estou já deitado, mas amanhã se você completar sua pergunta, explico melhor como pode fazer. Caso tenha muita pressa, você pode fazer mais alguma pesquisa sobre persistência de dados usando SharedPreference. Abs

Comment: obrigado pela ajuda amigo,tbm ja estou indo deitar....voce poderia me dizer do que precisa pra poder me ajuda? abs

Comment: obrigado mais uma vez, refiz o código e deu tudo certo, abs amigo

Comment: Legal cara! Sucesso aí pra ti!